# Создание уникального приложения Windows Form c#

Tags: c#, база-данных, windows, winforms

Уникальное - потому что нигде нет информации о таких проектах. Я пытаюсь написать приложение на тему писателей моей области, в котором пользователь сможет добавлять/удалять писателей и их биографию. Если конкретнее в главном меню будет набор кнопок с портретами писателей при нажатии на которые выводится информация о них.
 Я пытался сделать с помощью БД и winForm, но может есть способ предназначенный на такой случай или среда разработки?

Comment: Интерфейс к базе данных с CRUD-операциями — уникальное приложение?

Comment: @Vyacheslav Может быть вам следует создать такой сайт?

Comment: Проблема то в чем?

Comment: Winform, по моему будет достаточно неудобно... "в главном меню будет набор кнопок с портретами писателей...", наверное лучше использовать либо WPF, либо ASP (правда это будет уже "веб-приложение", но это наверное будет лучший вариант).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> пользователь сможет добавлять/удалять писателей и их биографию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
// Microsoft (R) Roslyn C# Compiler version 1.1.0.51204
#r "System.Windows.Forms"
#r "System.Data"

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

DataSet Load(string path) {
    var ds = new DataSet();
    if (File.Exists(path)) ds.ReadXml(path);
    else ds.ReadXml(new StringReader(@"<data><author name='a1'>bio1</author></data>"));
    return ds;
}

T Create<T>(Rectangle bounds, object data, string binding) where T : TextBoxBase, new() {
    var tb = new T() { Bounds = bounds };
    tb.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", data, binding) {
        DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged,
        ControlUpdateMode = ControlUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged,
    });
    return tb;
}
```

---

```
var f = new Form() { Width=650, Height=250 };
var ds = Load(@"c:\temp\db.xml");
new ListBox() { Parent=f, Bounds=new Rectangle(5,0,200, 190), 
                DataSource=ds, ValueMember="author.name" };
f.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {
  Create<TextBox>(new Rectangle(210,0,200,30), ds, "author.name"),
  Create<RichTextBox>(new Rectangle(210,35,415,150), ds, "author.author_Text")
});
f.Menu = new MainMenu(new[] {
    new MenuItem("add", (s,e) => { f.BindingContext[ds, "author"].AddNew(); }),
    new MenuItem("delete", (s,e) => {
        var bc = f.BindingContext[ds, "author"];
        bc.RemoveAt(bc.Position);
    }),
});
f.ShowDialog();
ds.WriteXml(@"c:\temp\db.xml");    // сохранить изменения
```

---

Для компиляции кода и запуска приложения, например, в Visual Studio Community 2015 надо открыть `View - Other Windows - C# Interactive`, скопировать в него код и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Visual Studio Community 2015 - бесплатная версия, ее можно скачать [тут](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48146).